# How to translate NOT (A AND B) into a mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, logic

I've built a grammar (using peg.js) to support simple search queries in a Node.js web-application; I need to translate the AST it produces into a `$match` parameter for a MongoDB aggregate function. Most cases are fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out what `NOT (A AND B)` should look like in MongoDB.

Some example data:

```
{ _id:123, labels:['a', 'b', 'c'], tags:['g', 'h', 'i']},
{ _id:456, labels:['a', 'e', 'f'], tags:['i', 'j', 'k']},
{ _id:789, labels:['c', 'd', 'b'], tags:['h', 'l', 'm']}
```

A user might type in the query `NOT (labels:a AND labels:b)`, or `NOT (labels:b AND tags:h)` which are both valid queries, based on my grammar.

The intent for the first query would be to bring back all documents that do not contain both 'a' and 'b' in their `labels` field (so the second and third document would be returned); for the second query, it should match all documents that do not contain both 'b' in the `labels` field, and 'h' in the `tags` field.

MongoDB's `$not` operator doesn't seem to allow you to neatly negate a logical operation in the way I'm looking for; ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
{
    $not: {
        $and: [
            { labels: a},
            { labels: b},
        ]
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    $not: {
        $and: [
            { labels: b},
            { tags: h},
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there some other operator I can use to do this? Also, ideally, this would be something easy to build programatically - so that I could build a potentially complex compound query inside the parentheses, and then just negate it if there was a `NOT`.

**EDIT**: Expanded the dataset, and expanded and clarified my actual requirements for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one field (as per the original question) this should do it:

```
{
    'labels': {
        '$not': {
            '$all': [
                'a',
                'b',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For multiple fields, you'd need to break them out but this query would work:

```
{
    '$and': [
        {
            'labels': {
                '$not': {
                    '$all': ['b'],
                },
            },
        },
        {
            'tags': {
                '$not': {
                    '$all': ['h'],
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't think it's possible to have the not as a main root element

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work perfectly for my initial question, and made me think more about what I need. In my initial post, I reduced the problem to its simplest form, which this is a good solution to, but I've edited my post to give more detail - unfortunately, I do not believe this is a solution to the expanded problem.

Comment: That would just be an expansion of the above, I'll add to my answer